# getting counts per username of the amount of files on which they were the last modifier

Tags: bash, powershell, filesystems, window, cygwin

I would like to get the counts per user name of how many files they edited (were the last user in editing that file) in an entire directory structure in the last 45 days.

Here's my desired output:

```
+-------+-----+
| alex  |   3 |
| liza  | 345 |
| harry | 564 |
| sally |  23 |
+-------+-----+
```

So far I have this powershell non-working script:

```
gci -Recurse| where {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-45)}| group owner|select count,owner
```

The solution can be in powershell or bash!

thank you for your guidance.

in my opinion the process should be:

1. get list of all files that were modified in the last 45 days
2. get all the usernames that modified the file most recently
3. do a group by username

Comment: "Files they edited" and "files they own" is not the same thing! Am I missing something?

Comment: @Celada thank you. i have clarified

Comment: @Celada please see more edits!

Comment: Well, filesystems don't track the identity of the user who changed a file. They only track the file's owner. Perhaps you could get the identity of the user who changed a file most recently from a version control system?

Comment: @Celada doesnt windows have the ACL which keeps track of it? \

Comment: @Celada if its not possible to do the last user who modified it then lets just do the owner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

powershell way:

```
gci -Recurse| where {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-45)}| 
 select @{n="Owner";e={ get-acl $_ | select -expa owner }} | select -expa owner | group  | select Count,name
```

edit for last comment (powershell 3.0):

```
$dirs = dir -Directory

foreach ( $dir in $dirs)
{      
 $a = dir $dir -r -File  |  select @{n="Owner";e={ get-acl $_.fullname | 
 select -expa owner }} | select -expa owner | group  | select Count,name

 $a | add-member -Name Path -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $dir -PassThru
}
```

powershell 2.0:

```
$dirs = dir | ? { $_.psiscontainer }
foreach ( $dir in $dirs)
{

 #$dir

 $a = dir $dir -r |? { -not $_.psiscontainer } |  select @{n="Owner";e={ get-acl $_.fullname | select -expa owner }} | select -expa owner | group  | select Count,name

 $a | add-member -Name Path -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $dir -PassThru
}
```

Comment: here's the output i am getting: Count Owner
----- -----
  620 {}

Comment: i tried this on other directories, and it shows only one owner again

Comment: now can i ask you, how can i run this script once for every directory in a parent directory. for example if i am in parent\, and parent dir has dir a, dir b, dir c, i want to run it once for each of those dirs?

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов try snippet.... is in powershell 3.0... if you are in 2.0 you have to change `-directory` and `-file` parameters with pipe to `where-object { $_.psiscontainer }` or `where-object { -not $_.psiscontainer }`

Comment: thanks so much! i am trying to upgrade to 3.0 but am unable to find download link!

Comment: actually could you please include a powershell 2.0 version, i wasnt sure what how to interpret your last comment

Comment: added v2.0, for v3.0 download (need windows 7) : http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595.  Now you can accept my answer ;)

Comment: thank you soooooo much!! worked brilliantly!!! can i ask you a few questions about powershell in chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23813/discussion-between---and-c-b)

Answer (score 1):

Filesystems don't track the identify of the most recent user who edited a file, but they do track the file's owner. If you want to look at a count of recently modified files by owner, you can try this:

```
find . -not -mtime +45 -printf %u\\n | sort | uniq -c
```

Piece by piece, this means:

- Find all files that were NOT modified 45 or more days ago:

  ```
  find . -not -mtime +45
  ```
- for each file, print the file's owner:

  ```
  -printf %u\\n
  ```
- group and count the results:

  ```
  | sort | uniq -c
  ```

Comment: thanks so much! im getting something weird:    621 ????????
     54 Administrators

Comment: That may be an unfortunate consequence of how cygwin maps MS Windows usernames to UNIX user IDs. Maybe that's what cygwin "sees" as the UNIX owner of a MS Windows file. I can tell you that the above command works fine in Linux and in MacOS. If it's a cygwin or MS Windows issue then I'm sorry, I don't know how to solve it. Basically though: under cygwin, whatever `ls -l` shows as being the owner of the file, the `find` command should be seeing the same thing. So try `ls -l` on vaious sample files and see what you get. If `ls -l` shows useless usernames like `??????` then that's the reason.

Comment: thank you very much! i will wait a while to see if anyone who knows powershell can figure this out and if not i will have to mark this as an answer because it is absolutely correct as you say

Answer (score 1):

Using PowerShell 3:

```
ls -r | ? LastAccessTime -gt (get-date).AddDays(-45) | get-acl | group Owner -no
```

Broken down:

1. find all files recursively
2. use only files younger than 45 days by using date/time arithmetic
3. get the security descriptor
4. group by the owner property, throw away the elements (we need only the count)

Answer (score 0):

here's a very basic script that could help you get there:

```
$ cat findfilesbyuser.sh
#!/usr/bin/bash

searchdir="$1"
filelist=`find "$searchdir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%u:%p\n"`
userlist=`echo "$filelist" | cut -d: -f1 | sort -u`

echo "username:filecount"

while read uname
 do
  userfilecount=`grep -c "^"$uname":" <<< "$filelist"`
  echo "$uname:$userfilecount"
 done <<< "$userlist"
```

here's how i call it, and its output:

```
$ ./findfilesbyuser.sh /cygdrive/h
username:filecount
Administrators:1
user01:13
user02:24
```

you will likely run into some problems with cygwin presenting some user names as ??????, but unfortunately, that's unavoidable if you're using the bash solution to scan files created on windows.

hth!

Comment: looks like you might have windows line endings in your script.  try `dos2unix ./findfilesbyuser.sh`, then try it again.

Comment: new output" $ ./findfilesbyuser.sh
./findfilesbyuser.sh: line 1: $: command not found
find: `': No such file or directory
username:filecount
:0

Comment: in cygwin, run `which bash` and tell me the output please

Comment: oh, i see what went wrong.  you need to pass a directory name to the script as an argument.  call it as `./findfilesbyuser.sh dirname`

Comment: i am in /cygdrive/z, and there's a dir called vt.......gordon@HO-D26Q3M1 /cygdrive/z
$ ./findfilesbyuser.sh vt
-bash: ./findfilesbyuser.sh: No such file or directory

Comment: ok, try this: navigate to the folder containing the file findfilesbyuser.sh, then enter: `./findfilesbyuser.sh /cygdrive/z/vt`

Comment: $ ./findfilesbyuser.sh /cygdrive/z/vt
./findfilesbyuser.sh: line 1: $: command not found
username:filecount
????????:16
Administrators:3